# Ambiguous Debug using Visual Studio Immediate Window for VB.net Web Forms Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

This is probably really stupid, but I'm relatively new to VB and Dot.net, and I can't find a proper analog anywhere online.  Every time, using the Immediate window, I type `Debug.Print(x)`, I get the following message:

> `error BC30561: 'Debug' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web.Util, System.Diagnostics, System.Configuration'.`

If I type out `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print`, it works fine, but I'm hoping there is away to avoid the extra typing.

Little help?

**Note:**  I have `System.Diagnostics` referenced as an `imported namespace` at the project level.

Comment: Recent Solution *upgrade*? Multiple libraries versions? Open up Object Browser, search `Debug` and see what comes out.

Comment: The context is not obvious from the question.  Try typing `?x` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019):

> The Immediate window evaluates expressions by building and using the
>   currently selected project.

When you enter `Debug.Print("...")` in the immediate window, it is treated as an expression to be evaluated and as such it wrapped in the current context and built and executed. Since you have imported ,`System.Web.Util`, `System.Configuration` and `System.Diagnostics` and there is a [System.Configuration.Debug Class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/Debug.cs,5bedd70e9f327511) and a [System.Web.Util.Debug class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/Debug.cs,a73f9e1751f3164c) defined in addition to the one in `System.Diagnostics`, you get the error

> error BC30561: 'Debug' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or
>   types 'System.Web.Util, System.Configuration, System.Diagnostics,
>   System.Configuration'.

even though those two other classes are not strictly accessible from your code.  This is due to VB allowing importing both namespaces and classes.  Note that conflict this only occurs in the Immediate Window and not in user code.

If you want to issue a `Debug.Print` command in the Immediate window, issue it as a *command* without the parentheses by first entering a **>** before the command.

```
>Debug.Print "some expression"
```

Or use the `Debug.Print` command alias **?**.

```
? "some expression"
```

Comment: This is great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Click on the project properties and choose 'References', as shown in the image below surrounding with red. Then be sure that System.Diagnostics is check, see surrounding with red.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me. Try removing System.Web.Util. and the other one

Answer (score 1):

try this import

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
```

(place it above "Public Class ...")

Comment: I should've mentioned that I have it as an imported namespace already at a project level.  Should I still do this?